# Does storing apples alongside potatoes keep potatoes from sprouting?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

I am looking for a chemical explanation which I wasn't able to find.

I have read in several sources such as [this one](https://lifehacker.com/store-potatoes-with-an-apple-to-keep-them-from-sproutin-5954159) that, in order to prevent potatoes from sprouting, it is sufficient to store a few apples alongside them. This is due to the fact that the apples produce ethylene.

But this is a bit odd, since the ethylene is typically a ripening agent. [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/pwl4j/does_ethylene_gas_prevent_or_cause_potatoes_to/) also discusses the same doubt, but doesn't dive much into the details. There is also [this article](https://hamodia.com/columns/do-apples-keep-potatoes-from-sprouting-its-complicated/) and [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-apples-keep-potatoes-from-sprouting), none of which give a specific chemical reason about why and how this works.

Chemically speaking, do we actually know the exact reason and the necessary conditions to make this work?

Comment: Where I am the conventional wisdom is to *not* store apples and potatoes together (nor potatoes and onions) and ethylene is given as reason. But then, this conventional wisdom is not about storing potatoes for a few weeks but for months, so that you'd get from the first freezing in fall till early potatoes are ripe (they will be shriveled by then and also sprouting, but not rotting).

Comment: Ethylene only makes *fruit* that is very nearly ripe take the last step. The potatoe is not a fruit (the fruit grows above the earth and is slightly poisonous), so any possible effect would have to be sth different.

Comment: @Karl: there are also so-called ethylene-sensitive vegetables, e.g. cauliflower or red cabbage - neither of which is a fruit. Have a loo e.g. at https://unitedworldtransportation.com/ethylene-and-produce-sensitivity/ or if you read German: https://www.lebensmittellexikon.de/e0002410.php

Comment: I sometimes down-vote accidentally because the buttons are too small on my phone. Once you make that mistake, you can't undo it until the question gets edited. In any case, the majority thinks it is a good question, and you are getting credit for that. I wouldn't worry about down-votes.

Comment: @KarstenTheis : Thanks. I think they've implemented that hand-waving sign under the username for a reason. Most likely because they thought downvoting a _new contributor_'s post without giving a single explanation is typically interpreted as being mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ethylene has been used in storing potatoes for a while, see this [article](https://potatoes.ahdb.org.uk/sites/default/files/publication_upload/R279%20Research%20Review%20Ethylene.pdf). In it, they address the puzzle of a ripening agent acting to prevent sprouting:

> Sprout suppressant properties   of   apple   ‘vapours’   were   first   reported   in   1932   and   subsequently,  ethylene  and  apple  ‘vapours’  in  1933  (Elmer  and  Huelin,  respectively).    This  was  preceeded,  however,  by  work  demonstrating  a  ‘dormancy  breaking’  effect  of  ethylene  (Rosa,  1925).    These  apparently  conflicting  responses  to  ethylene  were  resolved  with  the  publication of work showing both effects, but under different ethylene exposure conditions.

The mechanism of the different effects are largely unknown. The cited article (by the British Potato Council) gives some references. Potatoes treated with ethylene do have slightly different properties (they mention the color after deep frying), and there is ongoing research to get an overview of all the differences.

> [OP:] Chemically speaking, do we actually know the exact reason and the necessary conditions to make this work?

We don't know the exact reason, but there are companies who figured out how to make this work in a warehouse under controlled conditions. I think on your shelf would be more difficult because you have no way of monitoring the ethylene concentration, so the apples might influence the potatoes in etiher way.

Comment: So the answer to the last sentence in my question is **NO**?

Comment: @polfosol - I updated my answer. The answer is no for the first part (mechanism is largely unknown), and yes for the second (conditions are known at industrial scale). Thanks for asking the question - fascinating stuff!

Comment: Great, +1. Another substance that is used to inhibit sprouting in potatoes is S-carvone. So maybe we could try to put the caraway on the potatoes long before cooking ;-) see e.g. https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10847-006-9210-2 (they used both S-carvone and caraway seeds (and some other treatments), and also caraway seeds inhibited sprouting - applying S-carvone directly was more effective in one experiment, but lead to rot in another)